# Publish data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

How can I make our software's data available as an app in Power BI so our customers can choose to integrate their data in Power BI?

I know there is a Rest API and I have seem many samples of how to use this for internal software.  However I don't want each customer to have to create an api application.  I want our app to appear like Salesforce & Zendesk etc. do so the customer can simply pick us from the list.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You're asking for a business cooperation. Either your name/app is as big/well-requested by users as Salesforce and Zendesk for Power BI to integrate itself or you should contact Microsoft Power BI directly for cooperation. Either way, you still need to develop an interface (API) for Microsoft to integrate it with Power BI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have helped a client of mine work through the process and it involves working with Microsoft to get the public content pack published. The process is outlined [here](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-content-pack-overview/). I would start by following the steps indicated there like filling out the nomination form and reaching out to support before you begin. There are a number of constraints around authentication and APIs and refresh you need to be aware of before you begin development and it is best to discuss this with support.